# Trying to make responsive divs side by side without overlapping.

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm not very experienced at this yet, so this problem might seem trivial. I've tried to research a fix for this problem and ran into similar questions on this site, but none of them seem to be applicable for this particular situation (maybe I'm wrong on that).

What I'm trying to do is get one div, which contains 3 soundcloud song embeds, to sit beside another, which contains a twitter feed (sitting left and right respectively). I want them to both be responsive. So as soon as the window gets narrower than the width of their container, I want them both to start responding and not to overlap.

So far, I've got them next to each other. I've done this by positioning the twitter feed over the soundcloud div and giving it margin-left: auto. I gave them each a max-width that adds up to the width of the container. Max-width was the only way I was able to keep them responsive.

What happens now is that as the window gets narrower, the twitter feed overlaps the soundcloud songs until about the halfway point. Then the soundncloud section starts re-sizing until the twitter feed completely overlaps it and starts re-sizing as well. So I need them to both stay on screen at the same time and both respond as the screen gets narrower.

Here's what I've got for my CSS:

```
#topcontainer {
max-width: 960px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#twitterfeed  {

max-width: 350px;
position: relative;
top: -599;
margin-left: auto;
}

.soundcloud {
max-width: 610px;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple column grid system that you might be able to incorporate into your design.

http://jsfiddle.net/3k7xY/1/

Basically, we will use media queries to determine how we will structure the page. In this Fiddle, I push the third column down once we reach a certain size and below. In this case, the size is `450px`.

You can play with the sizing as long as you use a similar structure.